# Shell loop through all files in specific directory

Tags: shell

How to loop through all files in specific directory using shell script? I have a directory located in the current working directory, which is .temp. Inside .temp there's another directory index, which has some files.

I have tried the following:

```
for file in ./.temp/index/*
do 
  echo "File in index: $file"
done 

for file in "./.temp/index"/*
do 
  echo "File in index: $file"
done
```

However, it prints `$file` as `./.temp/index/$file`. For example:

```
File in index: ./.temp/index/first.txt
File in index: ./.temp/index/second.txt
File in index: ./.temp/index/third.txt
...
```

Is there POSIX compliant way to loop through actual files in that directory?

Comment: What do you mean by "actual files"? If you just want the filename part try `$(basename "$file")`

Comment: @DSzum : The output you posted is actually correct. `file` takes in each iteration one entry in `.temp/index`. The only problem is that it would also show subdirectories as being files. You could use `[ -f "$file" ]` to test whether `file` holds the path of a **plain** file.

Comment: `echo 'File in index: '"${file##*/}"`

Answer (score 0):

```
for _file in `find . -type f`;
do
    echo "File: $_file";
done
```

`-type f` will find files in the directory. You can add additional filters as required.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the use of a loop all together by using find and -printf using %f to print the file names only:

```
find ./.temp/index -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "File in index: %f\n"
```